# A fairy tale in a golden toy

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

Once upon a time, long long ago, in the days when good stories were far more beautiful and far harder to come by, a king was asked by his spoilt but beloved princess daughter to give her a fairy tale. In answer to her request, he bestowed upon her a mysterious golden toy. Below you will find a perfectly faithful reproduction of it. Like all good princesses, she played diligently with her new plaything, until she revealed the tale it contained, a magnificent story of all-encompassing revulsion and allure.

Can *you* discover the fairy tale in the image? You will find there both the title of the story *and* the key plot point.

---

[image: Puzzle]

---

**Hint**:

> The fairy tale is not, of course, hidden in the png file itself, but rather in the thing which it represents, and this quite exactly. It should, for instance, be possible to build a physical version of the toy from which the solution might be obtained; no part of the toy is irrelevant to this solution.

---

**Hint 2**:

> Since this puzzle seems to have attracted some further interest, let me reiterate my point that this is essentially a mechanical puzzle. While it is difficult to hint the details of the puzzle's mechanism without giving the problem away, the essential mechanical processes involved are already hinted in the flavourtext. While I have stated a physical version might be built, simple pen-and-paper work should also yield a solution - it might help not to get too hung up in precise lengths and angles, while keeping careful track of where different physical components might lie.

---

**Hint 3**:

> I'm wary of placing bounties or posting too many hints on my old questions to avoid making a nuisance of myself with puzzles that aren't very interesting, but since this puzzle has garnered ongoing attention, and has attracted (another!) bounty placed by some kind stranger, first @Swati, now @costello (as well as a downvote...), I'll post another clearer hint.
>
> The image is all you need to solve the puzzle (although some of the physical details of the mechanical processes involved are obscurely hinted in the flavourtext). I reiterate that a working physical model of this puzzle could be built. The pictured state is one possible arrangement of the machine, and the solution state(s?) may be found by manipulating the machine. @SeptaCube has performed a manipulation of the image (rotating the thick lines) which is crucial to obtaining the solution - what is now required is to rationalise and finetune this manipulation (using the other components of the image - black and white dots, thin lines, and pattern at lower right). There is one wrinkle, which is the obvious elongation of the image (initially unintentional and an artifact of the program I used to construct the image), but which is easily corrected (by stretching the image, assuming near-right angles are right, and interpreting the elongation as a perspective view of the physical toy). The arrow at lower right does not need to be stretched in the same manner. Once this stretch is performed, the puzzle is mathematically precise to the pixel (hence the mathematics tag), but this is not necessarily the desired method, for *even without it* it is still solveable by hand - some tweaking of @Septacube's image should start to show some recognizable shapes.

Comment: There is a face in the image with a very pointed chin.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields lol I'm not 100% sure I can see it

Comment: Gur vzntr pbagnvaf guvf va ercrgvgvba m¶Û (bognvarq guebhtu fgrtnabtencuvp qrpbqvat bs gur vzntr ([here](https://stylesuxx.github.io/steganography/)))

Comment: @JohnBrookfields I feel like the princess long long ago would have had trouble solving it if the solution had been merely inserted steganographically into my png file (and don't ask me what that website does ;)

Comment: I read "don't ask me what that golden toy does".

Comment: I think gur neebj vf gryyvat hf gb ebgngr bar uhaqerq guvegl svir qrterrf pbhagrepybpxjvfr.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for a hint?

Comment: @mestackoverflow Done!

Comment: Does these  things represent some movable dials?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Creuncf na vqrn gung znl or jbegu chefhvat....

Comment: Perhaps another hint? This looks like a very nice puzzle and it would be great if it was solved!

Comment: I'm too lazy to do anything with this, but it seems to me this might be a rot13(zbovyr. Creuncf vs vg vf uhat sebz gur evtug cbvag (znlor vaqvpngrq ol gur neebj), naq gur juvgr/oynpx raqcbvagf ner vagrecergrq pbeerpgyl, vg zvtug erirny n zrffntr.)

Comment: Why is there a mathematics tag? It dosen't seem as if the problem involves some math, unless...

Comment: Rot13(Pnyphyhf)?

Comment: @Anonymus25 The puzzle can be solved by rough pen-and-paper trial and error, and that is probaby the best way to approach it. However, it could also be solved more exactly using relevant mathematics (exactly how will become obvious once you figure out the principles involved in the problem).

Comment: "I'm wary of placing bounties or posting too many hints on my old questions to avoid making a nuisance of myself with puzzles that aren't very interesting" - I think people are definitely interested (I know I am), just haven't figured out a starting point! I'd recommend adding hints until it's solved - better to make the puzzle too easy than to leave it unsolved, IMO.

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks for the encouragement! I guess it's a fine line... At the same time there are puzzles I've posted that've attracted little interest, for which I feel there's no point posting hints until it is trivial (plus at least once someone answered such a puzzle out of the blue). There've even been a couple of mine that got a fair no. of upvotes, but no partials, even though the 1st steps were simple. In those cases, the vibe I got that people weren't really interested in the techniques involved (which is obviously fine) made me feel there was no point cluttering the site with hint edits.

Comment: A faithful reproduction on geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/bgafwzvf

Answer (score 8):

> Rotating each black segment / set of segments around the corresponding point in ways that make sense give this image:
>
>  [image]
>
>  When turned upside down, this seems to resemble the straw and brick houses in the three little piggies story, making that the answer.

Comment: You're well and truly on the right track, although finding the actual solution will require a slightly more systematic approach. Your answer doesn't take into account many of the visual components of the image, nor does it really tell us the title of the story and plot point; your fairy tale doesn't really match the flavourtext either I feel. Your approach though is good - rationalise it (using the rest of the image data) and you should be closer to the solution.

Comment: In fact, with a few tweaks to your own solution, an alternative image might start to appear...

Comment: Spoiler fixed for you - feel free to make any further edits as required :)

Comment: Rot 13: Gur guvat gung’f ernyyl obgurevat zr vf ubj aba-fcrpvsvp gur qbgf ner.  Gur yvarf V haqrefgnaq ner (V guvax?) whfg hfrq nf ybbfr pbaarpgbef, ohg gur qbgf qba’g frrz gb yvar hc jvgu nalguvat... N qrprag puhax yvr ba yvarf, ohg V gevrq gb cbvag gur oynpx cbvag yvarf va gur qverpgvba bs gur juvgr qbgf, naq fvzvyne guvatf, ohg abguvat...

Comment: Also thanks for fixing my answer Stiv.

Comment: V’z cerggl pbasvqrag nobhg gur pheirq yvarf orvat fgevat naq arprffvgngvat n fgngr bs gur qvnyf jurer gur pbaarpgvba pna or znqr jvguva gur tvira yratgu, be whfg nalguvat vaibyivat gurz orvat chyyrq gnhg.  Znlor gur fgevatf nsgre orvat chyyrq gnhg znxr yrggref?  Gung frrzf gur zbfg yvxryl guvat gb npghnyyl fcryy bhg n gvgyr.

Comment: Gur qbgf unir n irel fcrpvsvp zrnavat. Creuncf vg jvyy uryc gb xabj gung V qvq abg cynpr gurz ol unaq - gur cynprzrag bs znal vzntr pbzcbaragf jnf qvpgngrq ol n zngurzngvpny zbqry; va fbzr pnfrf gur erfhygf ner pbhagrevaghvgvir, ohg bapr lbh ernyvfr gur zrnavat bs gur guvpx oynpx yvarf, oynpx naq juvgr qbgf, gurve cynprzrag jvyy znxr frafr ol rlr. Vg zvtug uryc gb xabj gung gur culfvpny irefvba bs gur chmmyr jbhyq jbex jvgubhg gur pheirq yvarf; gurl ner ubjrire cneg bs gur chmmyr 'vafgehpgvbaf' gung eraqre fbyinoyr n ceboyrz gung jbhyq or bgurejvfr or sne gbb oebnq naq punyyratvat...

Comment: My thoughts if anyone else wants to take a stab at this: 
Jung V'z cerggl fher nobhg:
Gur guvpx oynpx yvarf ebgngr nebhaq gur fznyy oynpx qbg.  
Gur erfhygvat ebgngvba erfhygf va zhygvcyrf bs 45 qrterr natyrf (gurl'er ybpxrq ba n tevq).  
Fznyy yratgu/natyr inevngvbaf qba'g znggre, fvapr gur ragver vzntr vf rybatngrq ubevmbagnyyl n yvggyr.  
Gur pbaarpgvat pheirq yvarf qba'g znggre, whfg juvpu pvepyrf gurl pbaarpg.  

Jung V'z abg fher nobhg:
Jurgure vavgvny natyrf bs oynpx yvarf znggre.  
Onfvpnyyl nalguvat cregnvavat gb jung gur pvepyrf zrna.

Comment: @Septacube Lbh'er rffragvnyyl pbeerpg. Ertneqvat gur fyvtug rybatngvba - guvf jnf abg vagragvbany, ohg na negvsnpg bs gur cebtenz (naq V'z fgvyy abg 100% fher bs vgf trarfvf); vg jnf guhf vagebqhprq nsgre gur cerpvfr zngurzngvpny fgrcf hfrq gb cynpr gur pbzcbaragf, ohg vg fubhyqa'g trg va gur jnl bs n fbyhgvba ol unaq. Lbh'er zbfgyl evtug nobhg gur zrnavat bs gur pheirq yvarf orvat rffragvnyyl whfg eryrinag va grezf bs gurve raqcbvagf. Gur xrl jvyy or ryhpvqngvat gur oynpx naq juvgr qbgf' zrnavat va eryngvba gb gur guvpx oynpx yvarf, nf jryy nf gur cnggrea ng gur ybjre evtug.

Answer (score 3):

I think the story is:

> "The Princess and the Frog"

> When you rotate the pieces around to form shapes, and then rotate them to point the "arrow" in the direction of the arrow on screen, they form what looks like a princess head (like, with little pigtails) and an origami-looking frog. And there's a single line between them which looks like a princess kissing a frog. In addition, the puzzle text hints at "revulsion and allure" which seems pretty appropriate.

Here's the image:

> [image]

Comment: Lbh'er zhpu pybfre guna zvtug or gubhtug, nygubhtu V nqzvg V'z univat gebhoyr frrvat gur cevaprff (V nffhzr vg'f lbhe funcr ba gur gbc yrsg?). Bapr gur fbyhgvba vf sbhaq, lbh'yy frr jul lbhe nafjre vf fb pybfr (ng yrnfg va gur raqcbvag).

Comment: Lbhe vqrn bs ebgngvat gur funcrf gb cbvag gbjneqf gur neebj vf vagrerfgvat, naq juvyr abg ragveryl pbeerpg vf ba gur evtug genpx. Fb sne, obgu choyvfurq fbyhgvbaf unir vaibyirq ebgngvat gur guvpx oynpx cvrprf nq ubp; gur tbny vf gb svaq gur fgevpg culfvpny ynj tbireavat gurve ebgngvba (nygubhtu gur vzntrf bs obgu @frcgnphor naq lbhefrys ner pybfr rabhtu gung n srj zber nq ubp ebgngvbaf zvtug fgneg gb fubj n zber erpbtavfnoyr vzntr).

Comment: Creuncf vg jbhyq uryc lbh vs V erzvaqrq lbh gung na ragveryl culfvpny zbqry bs gur chmmyr pbhyq or znqr, naq gbyq lbh gung va guvf zbqry, lbh jbhyq abg arrq gb ebgngr gur guvpx oynpx yvarf lbhefrys (naq cbvagrq bhg gung nyy-rapbzcnffvat erihyfvba naq nyyher zvtug uvag gb fbzr fcrpvsvp culfvpf)...

Comment: @Anon Lrnu, zl vavgvny gubhtug jnf gung vg jnf ersrerapvat zntargvfz, juvpu znxrf n gba bs frafr tvira gur pbaarpgvat juvgr naq oynpx qbgf. V fcrag n juvyr gelvat gb trg fbzrjurer jvgu gung naq jnf hanoyr gb.

Comment: Gur guvat gung'f ernyyl guebjvat zr bss vf gung fbzr bs gur "zntargf" yrg'f pnyy gurz? Nera'g pbaarpgrq gb nalguvat, fb V pna'g svther bhg jung V'z fhccbfrq gb qb jvgu gurz. Naq sbe fbzr bs gur funcrf, vg'f hapyrne vs vg'f n fvatyr jubyr funcr be gur cvrprf ner crezvggrq gb zbir vaqrcraqragyl. Onfvpnyyl, V srry yvxr V qba'g unir rabhtu vasbezngvba gb fbyir guvf chmmyr. Lbh xrrc fnlvat naq uvagvat gung gur cvpgher vf zngurzngvpnyyl cerpvfr ohg gung qbrfa'g uryc vs V pna'g svther bhg gur haqreylvat zrpunavfzf. :-/

Comment: V guvax lbh'er irel pybfr urer. Vs ol zntargf lbh zrna gur ynetr oynpx qbgf (va juvpu pnfr lbh'er zbfg pregnvayl svthevat bhg ubj gur znpuvar jbexf), gura nyy bs gurz hayrff V'z zhpu zvfgnxra ner yvaxrq ol n guva yvar gb bar bs gur juvgr qbgf. Jung'f gura yrsg ner gur guvpx oynpx yvarf naq fznyy oynpx qbgf, naq lbh frrz gb unir nffhzrq (pbeerpgyl) gung gur sbezre cvibg nebhaq gur ynggre juvpu ner svkrq.

Comment: Vs gurer ner zntargf va gur vzntr gura, jung (uvagrq) glcr bs zrpunavpny bowrpg zvtug gur arrqyr-yvxr guvpx oynpx yvarf ercerfrag? Orsber lbh pbzcynva gung gur zntargf' ybpngvba qbrf abg pbzcyrgryl rkcynva gur guvpx oynpx yvarf' bevragngvba, znxr fher lbh'er abg vtabevat bar irel vzcbegnag erny-jbeyq snpgbe jura cynlvat jvgu zntargf naq arrqyrf.

Comment: Note that as you suspect, the mathematics alone will not provide enough information to completely solve the puzzle - once you have the mechanics figured out, some trial and error in the spirit of what yourself and @SeptaCube have already done will be required, but it will be significantly simpler and more focussed once you have mechanical constraints.